# Overriding compareTo method of Object Class

Tags: java, overriding

Can someone please explain to me what the following code does. I am new to programming. I am having a hard time understanding what is meant by "the current object."
This code is contained within a class that implements the Compareable  interface. It has a conscutor that takes an int number and String description. It also has a get method for both number and description.

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo (Object o)
    {
        Item i = (Item) o;
        if (this.getNumber () < i.getNumber())
            return -1;
        if (this.getNumber () > i.getNumber())
            return 1;
        return 0;
```

Comment: Honestly, if you don't know what "the current object" (`this`) is then you've probably jumped in too deep. Go get an introductory Java textbook and start at the beginning. Once you get more OO background this will make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Item i = (Item) o;
```

This line casts the incoming object **o** as the **Item** class, then stores it on **i**.

```
if (this.getNumber () < i.getNumber())
```

This line compares **the object you're receiving** to **the one you're calling the method from**, particularly their number fields.

```
return 0;
```

This line is only reached if none of the previous conditionals were met. In this case, it returns 0 when this.getNumber() equals i.getNumber().

```
int x = objectOne.compareTo(objectTwo);
```

This hypothetical line would assign the corresponding return value to **x**.

For example, if objectOne.getNumber() is less than objectTwo.getNumber(), x would be assigned a -1 value.

Answer (score 0):

`compareTo()` returns an `int` to indicate whether or not the compared value is bigger (1), equal (0) or smaller (-1). What's the problem?

Comment: It should compile fine—the space between `getNumber` and the `()` shouldn't cause any harm.

Comment: Nitty-picking it won't compile because of a missing `}` ;)

Comment: @DaoWen: you're correct, I'm baffled why this doesn't give a compilation error. I guess I never actually wrote it like that and always assumed it would be a syntax error.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - You can put spaces around the `.` operator as well. Yeah, it's weird style, but when you think about it from a parsing perspective it makes sense. If you can put spaces around operators like `+`, `-`, etc. then why not `.` and `()`?

Comment: @DaoWen: fair point, I guess that could be a reason why. Those help with readability though, `.` and `()` would actually make it less readable to me. Thanks for clearing it up though!